# Not able to pass array of objects in sendKeys() [in Selenium Javascript]

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, foreach, mocha.js, arrayofstring

I'm currently trying to perform parameterised testing using Mocha in Selenium.

I'm passing multiple values into a text-box(s). When using simple arrays, I'm able to pass the array data in `sendKeys()` function and successfully complete the test (refer below code):

```
const {By,Key,Builder} = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("edgedriver");
const assert = require("assert");

describe("dyndataTest1", function() {

    const URL = "https://www.google.com/";

    const colors = ["blue", "green","red"];

    colors.forEach((googlesearch) => {
        it(`googlesearch1 for search key - ${googlesearch}`, async function() {

            let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').build();

            await driver.manage().setTimeouts({implicit:10000});
            await driver.get(URL);
            await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(googlesearch, Key.RETURN);

            await driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).clear();
            await driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).sendKeys(googlesearch, Key.RETURN);
                            
            let verifyText = await driver.getTitle().then (function (value) {
                return value;
            });
            console.log(verifyText);
            assert.strictEqual(verifyText, googlesearch + " - Google Search");

            await driver.quit();
        });
    });

});
```

I tried the same again, but this time passed an array of objects instead of a simple array, using similar code below:

```
const {By,Key,Builder} = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("edgedriver");
const assert = require("assert");

const colors = [
    { googlesearch1:"blue", googlesearch2:"green", googlesearch3:"red" },
    { googlesearch1:"sky_blue", googlesearch2:"forest_green", googlesearch3:"brick_red" },
];

describe("dyndataTest2", function() {

    const URL = "https://www.google.com/";

    colors.forEach(({googlesearch1, googlesearch2, googlesearch3}) => {
        it(`googlesearch for search key - ${googlesearch1},${googlesearch2},${googlesearch3}`, async function() {

            let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').build();

            await driver.manage().setTimeouts({implicit:10000});
            await driver.get(URL);
            await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(googlesearch1, Key.RETURN);

            await driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).clear();
            await driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).sendKeys(googlesearch2, Key.RETURN);

            await driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).clear();
            await driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).sendKeys(googlesearch3, Key.RETURN)

            let verifyText =  driver.getTitle().then (function (value) {
                return value;
            });
            console.log(verifyText);
            assert.strictEqual(verifyText, googlesearch3 + " - Google Search");

            await driver.quit();
        });
    });

});
```

However, on running the 2nd code block, I'm getting the output in console as `Promise { <pending> }`, which means I have to return the promise to Mocha, which I'm unsure of how to insert in the code when using `forEach()` loop.

Here is the console output:

```
dyndataTest2
Promise { <pending> }
    1) googlesearch for search key - blue,green,red
Promise { <pending> }
    2) googlesearch for search key - sky_blue,forest_green,brick_red


  0 passing (34s)
  2 failing

  1) dyndataTest2
       googlesearch for search key - blue,green,red:
     AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected values to be strictly equal:
+ actual - expected

+ Promise {
+   <pending>
+ }
- 'red - Google Search'
      at Context.<anonymous> (Test Scripts/dyndataTest2.js:33:20)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

  2) dyndataTest2
       googlesearch for search key - sky_blue,forest_green,brick_red:
     AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected values to be strictly equal:
+ actual - expected

+ Promise {
+   <pending>
+ }
- 'brick_red - Google Search'
      at Context.<anonymous> (Test Scripts/dyndataTest2.js:33:20)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Can someone tell me where and how I should insert the promise callback to fix this code?

What I require is to perform the following set of identical tests in succession using one loop:

1. Open browser | launch google | search: blue (clear search) , green (clear search) , red | Close browser
2. Open browser | launch google | search: sky_blue (clear search) , forest_green (clear search) , brick_red | Close browser